# Resize Primefaces Dialog

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I wanna know in primefaces 3.4 and above how can I resize a p:dialog; the reason is that I need to show a dialog and when the user submit some information the same dialog must be update with the new information, and resize the dialog. I'm doing the first but not the second one.

Comment: This answer could help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16594037/354831

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to position a p:dialog in Prime Faces after its resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576417/how-to-position-a-pdialog-in-prime-faces-after-its-resizing)